# Working around error in a looping when there are no values in the column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function soccerway() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Soccerway");
  
  if (ss.getRange("A2").getValues()[0][0] ==  "ATIVO") {
    var range;
    range = ss.getRange('F2:F31');
    var loop = range.getValues().flat().filter(e => e);
    var column = ss.getRange('H2:H');
    var values = column.getValues();
    var ct = 0;
    while (values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "") {
      ct++;
    }
    var valueArr = [];
    if(ct > 0){
      for (var key of loop) {
      var data = [[key,]]
      var contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch(key).getContentText();
      var $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
      var ElementSelect = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.container.left > a.team-title');
      var ElementSelect2 = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.container.right > a.team-title');
      var data1 = ElementSelect.text().trim() + '&&&&&' + ElementSelect.attr('href');
      var data2 = ElementSelect2.text().trim() + '&&&&&' + ElementSelect2.attr('href');
      valueArr.push([key, data1, data2]);
      }
    }
    ss.getRange(ct+2, 8, valueArr.length, 3).setValues(valueArr);
  }
}
```

The fact is that when there are **no** values in `Column H`, the code will throw an *error* because in `line 29` the ***number of lines in the range needs to be at least 1***, but using:

```
try {

} catch(e) {

}
```

Would make the code very large and repetitive because I would need to rewrite all the steps again inside to `catch(e)`.

Is there another simpler and faster way that I can use?

My Spreadsheet and Script:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kXC-aQEViFmL0KC-UG0YEpjmJq69gpSeH3HbbSetI4M/edit?usp=sharing

Additional information:

Whenever I activate the code I want the new data always be published in blank lines, I don't want it to overwrite the non blank cells.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, in your script, how about including `s.getRange(ct+2, 8, valueArr.length, 3).setValues(valueArr);` after for loop in the if statement of `if (ct > 0){}`? I thought that when `ct > 0` is `false`, `valueArr` is `[]`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike i add the link to Spreadsheet and Script

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Spreadsheet every cell in `F2:F31` either has a url or it is empty. In cells `H2:H` you have a value or not, and based on this you want to run a function on all rows where column H contains a value.

The following code outputs the following (from the API)

- Col H = url
- Col I = team 1 (formatted according to your code)
- Col I = team 1 (formatted according to your code)
- Col K = status (based on the current function exectution)

You can simplify your code by:

```
function getTeams(){
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Soccerway");

  // stop the function here if A2 is not ATIVO
  if( ss.getRange("A2").getValue() !=  "ATIVO" ) return

  const sourceRange = ss.getRange("F2:F31")
  const sourceVals = sourceRange.getValues()
  let startRow = 2


  // Run through each existing row / link
  sourceVals.forEach( (row, index) => {

    // Url is in Column A
    const url = row[0]

    // Current row number to output to
    const rowNum = startRow+index

    // Output will be in columns H:K
    const targetRange = ss.getRange( rowNum, 8, 1, 3)

    // Status will be ouput to column L
    const statusCell = ss.getRange(rowNum, 11)

    // skip if no url exists
    if( !url ) {
      statusCell.setValue("URL Missing")
      return 
    }

    // skip if values exist already
    let skip = false
    targetRange.getValues().forEach( row => {
      if( row[0] || row[1] ) skip = true
    })
   
    if( skip ){
      statusCell.setValue("Field skipped because values existed already")
      return
    } 

    // call the api
    const dataFromAPI = fetchDataForURL( url )
    
    // skip if no response from api
    if( !dataFromAPI || !dataFromAPI.url  || !dataFromAPI.data1 || !dataFromAPI.data2 ){
      statusCell.setValue("No Data from API")
      return
    } 
   
    // write response to sheet, after column H (I:J) 
    targetRange.setValues( [[dataFromAPI.url, dataFromAPI.data1, dataFromAPI.data2]] )
  });

  function fetchDataForURL( url ) {
    if( !url ) return

    var contentText = UrlFetchApp.fetch( url ).getContentText();
    var $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
    var ElementSelect = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.container.left > a.team-title');
    var ElementSelect2 = $('#page_match_1_block_match_info_5 > div > div > div.container.right > a.team-title');
    var data1 = ElementSelect.text().trim() + '&&&&&' + ElementSelect.attr('href');
    var data2 = ElementSelect2.text().trim() + '&&&&&' + ElementSelect2.attr('href');
      
    return {
      url: url,
      data1: data1,
      data2: data2
    }
  }
}
//
```

Comment: Hi mate @NevenSubotic , first of all I would like to thank you for your time and support. Google App Script has some limitations in the use of its code parameters, in its indication some errors appeared during the run, I added the question the link to the spreadsheet and access to the script to facilitate the tests for those who want to try to solve the problem. Anyway thanks for the information and I'll try to edit what didn't work to understand how I should proceed.

Comment: @BrondbyIF please see now. It helped to understand the sheet and its structure and I admit a mistake on my part. I've tried it in the url you shared and it works.

Comment: Hi mate, now we have a new problem, I'm doing the tests but when I activate the script again to make the other remaining urls, it is overwriting the existing ones. That's why it's a redundant problem, because if you have already registered games, it needs to continue from the first blank line, not overwrite existing ones. Would you help me?

Comment: I've added a script page called Neven Test so that I can separate the original and keep your attempt separate.

Comment: @BrondbyIF Done, I added a check. This should skip any rows where there is a value in one of the two cells in the target range

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but as soon as I can access the spreadsheet again, I'll try to find what I need to modify to resolve the issue. It keeps overwriting the data, error redundancy remains.

Comment: Check it now please, I corrected `if( !skip ) return` to `if( skip ) return`

Comment: Hi @NevenSubotic When data already exists I don't want to be overwritten, I want to skip these lines and the new values are added below the old ones.

Comment: Hi there @BrondyIF! The new updated code shouldn't overwrite your data. Could you please give it a try and share your findings?